# How would I identify a file to copy based on the date in its name?

Tags: vba, excel, filesystems

I am trying to copy a file from one path to another and rename it. However the source folder contains several files, and the naming convention is the following: `123456_EXyymmdd.txt` now the `123456` part is a randomly generated number, so I can only identify the file to copy for a given day by the `EXyymmdd` part. I have the following code where I tried to put the identifying segment of the string as `"**"` but it doesn't work, probably due to the date:

```
Sub SOQuestion()
Dim myDate1 As String
Dim Ipan1 As String
Dim Ipan2 As String
Dim mGlobalDate as string

mGlobalDate=Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
myDate1 = Format(Date, "yymmdd")
Ipan1 = "157782_EX" & mGlobalDate & ".txt"
Ipan2 = "*_EX*" & myDate1 & ".TXT*"

'source path below
FileCopy "C:\sample\" & Ipan2, "C:\sample2\" & Ipan1

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `mFilePath`?

Comment: ah sorry, it was copied from my macro and it was a global variable, let me edit the code

Comment: Do you get some sort of error?

Comment: I get Run-time error 52: Bad file name or number, I suppose it's due to the file not being identified properly.

Comment: Unfortunately the exact filename has a randomly generated number in its name, that's why it cannot be defined properly, that is my problem.

Comment: Use the `Dir(filePathWithWildcards)` to find the files that match the required pattern, then use the returned file name to get the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confused because of the wildcard. It would be like copying a bunch of files to one file, which if you think about it, doesn't make much sense. Instead, use the wildcard and the `Dir` function to get the exact filename and use that as your source argument.

```
Dim sFilename as String
sFilename = Dir("C:\sample\" & Ipan2)
```

Then:

```
FileCopy "C:\sample\" & sFilename, "C:\sample2\" & Ipan1
```

[MSDN Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)

Comment: Yep it works, trying to understand why haha. Thanks for your help!